# Как добавить файлы py к готовому меню, с помощью tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть несколько частей одного проекта. Хочу написать стартовое меню с помощью tkinter. Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывался файл .py и запускался код, написанный в нем(игра) Пробовала много чего, нигде не получается сделать именно так.[image: Вот примерно как оно должно выглядеть]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO! На данном сайте принято выкладывать непосредственно в вопрос весь свой код, чтобы Вам могли корректно ответить.

Answer (score 0):

Для вызова всего кода используйте строку `import code`, где *code* - название вашего файла. Эта строка сразу же запустит ваш код.

**Важно:** смотрите, чтобы название файла не совпадало с названием какой-либо библиотеки, а также с названием вашего файла. Также, если второй код, который вы вызываете из первого НЕ лежит в одной папке с первым, а например, находится в папке *folder*, то вызываем с указанием этой папки - `folder.code`

---

Если вам нужны только какие-то конкретные функции, то можно импортировать их вот так:

`from code import func, func2, func3`, где *func<1-3>* - название функций.

Если нужны вообще все функции, но они нигде не вызываются во втором коде, *(то есть при вызове `import code` ничего не происходит)* можно импортировать весь код, а затем вызвать нужную функцию вот так: `code.func1()`